# Is it possible to know the last call duration in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, call, duration

Can I take the last call duration in iPhone by code? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is if the user called from your app, and automatically gets back to your app at the end of the call.

Then you can take a time stamp when the call started, before your app was terminated, and when your app goes back in :

```
 -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

you can measure the time passed with the saved time stamp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain me how to "automatically" gets back to our app after calling?

Comment: That's possible only if the user called from your app